# In Python, how to ask for user to input a list, and then to be able to work with it, whatever data type, in a function

Tags: python

I am a pretty much complete beginner to Python, and I need to know how to ask the user to input a list which I can then work with. I know how to get a user to input ints, floats etc. and strings and then work with those, but I need help with getting a user to enter a list which is then changed to the, if not already, correct format of a list which I can then work with the values of in a function. Efficient code is good, but I'd prefer simple code which may take longer so I can understand it easier as a beginner. Any help is hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So do you want the user to input a bunch of items in one command and then add these all to a list?

If so then what you are looking for is the `str.split()` method. What this does is it gets a string and then splits this string into a list containing lots of substrings.

It has two arguments (the second is how many times to split, this should be left as default), the first being the delimiter. This is the string which the code should look for when splitting the string. By default, this value is a space, but you will probably want to change it.

To put all of this into perspective, here is an example which splits a string which is a list separated by commas and spaces:

```
inputtedListAsString = str(input("Please enter the items, separated by commas: "))
inputtedListAsArray = inputtedListAsString.split(", ")
```

If someone entered 'a, b, c, d, e' then it would return an array with 5 items, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' and 'e'. If you were to enter 'a, b, c, d, e, ' then this would return a list with 6 items, the sixth element in the list being an empty string.

Here is a more concise, one line example:

```
inputtedList = str(input("Please enter the items, separated by commas: ")).split(", ")
```

Also, to show you how the second argument in `str.split()` works, here is an example which will split a string with a delimiter of ' ', but limit it to split the string into only 3 parts:

```
limitedList = "Hello my name is Bob.".split(" ", 2)
```

This will return a list containing: 'Hello', 'my' and 'name is Bob.' Be aware that if you specify 2 as the second argument, the list will contain a maximum of 3 items, because the array counting starts at 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is no canonical method to input a list.
You could use eval, but eval means python will actually evaluate its argument, for exemple if you have

```
x = eval(input("Write a list"))
```

and the user inputs `[1,2]+[3*3,4]`, then x will contain the list `[1,2,9,4]`.
That's very good, but it's usually a mistake because it is in particular a security risk: your program is basically executing anything the user is typing.

If you don't want to use the eval function (and you shouldn't), here are basic solutions.

A first solution would be to ask the user for the number of elements in the list, and then ask for each element individually in a `for` loop.

Another solution, if the user has to input a list of int, would be to require him to write them separated by commas.
Then you could use something like:

```
x =  input("Write a list")
l = [int(i) for i in x.split(",")]
```

`x.split(",")` is splitting the input string into a list of strings (using the delimiter `","` to choose where to split), and the rest of the code is converting all strings into integers.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x you could use:

```
var = eval(input())
```

The user can then type

```
[1,2,3]
```

or

```
["a","b"]
```

However, be aware that in serious programming eval is considered unsafe.